# Inserir string com strtoupper

Tags: php, wordpress

Bom dia! Estou utilizando um código no WP para exibir notas musicais. Ele basicamente pega o texto de um shortcode "chord" e exibe na linha acima. Ele também converte o b (minúsculo) para ♭. Exemplo:

[image: Exemplo]

O problema é que ele converte tudo o que está no shortcode para maiúsculo, e eu não quero isso. Quero apenas que exiba o que for digitado.
No código dele eu encontrei a seguinte linha:

```
        $chordPretty = (strlen($chord)>1&&substr($chord, 1,1)==='b')? strtoupper(substr($chord, 0,1)).'♭' : strtoupper($chord);
```

Substituí ***strtoupper*** para ***strtolower*** para conferir se era realmente essa parte que fazia a conversão e de fato é. Como eu faço para chamar a string $chord substituindo b para ♭ mas sem alterar a caixa das letras?

Obrigado!

Comment: remova a função das 2 condições $chordPretty = (strlen($chord)>1&&substr($chord, 1,1)==='b')? substr($chord, 0,1).'♭' : $chord;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
$chordPretty = (strlen($chord)>1&&substr($chord, 1,1)==='b')? substr($chord, 0,1).'♭' : $chord;
```

Caso a string tenha mais que 1 caracter, e caso o segundo caracter seja 'b', ela retorna o primeiro caracter da string + ♭. Caso contrário, mantém o valor original.

Comment: Deu certo... Ele removeu o upper, mas há outra linha que está aplicando strtolower:

`$chord = strtolower($atts[0]);`

Eu posso definir $chord = $atts ?

Comment: Sim, para manter o estado da string, remova a função e deixe apenas $chord = $atts[0];

Comment: Sucesso! :)
Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Se a ideia é substituir tudo poderia simplesmente utilizar o  `str_replace` e o `strtoupper` para deixar tudo em caixa alta, se for o que deseja.

```
$listaDeSubstituição = [
    'b' => '♭'
];

$chord = strtr($chord, $listaDeSubstituição)

// Se quiser mudar "tudo" para maiúsculo:
// $chord = strtoupper($chord);

echo $chord;
```

Resultado:

```
Ab => A♭
F# => F#
C# => C#
```